# A Table object that accepts input and displays rows

Tags: python

I think my Table class may be doing too much. I feel as though I should perhaps create a separate `Input` class that deals with editing the table's rows.

My main problem is knowing when to create a new class. Is it true that the table is doing too much? Which things should be made into other classes, and why?

Btw, `Step` is a class that generates rows with correct data. It generates a dict.

The application outputs a table like this:

> ```
>     Step        Danger          Battle  Input
> 1 250 13  113 0    19200  74  False   Empty
> 2 252 13  113 113  55552  216 False   Empty
> 3 254 13  113 226  41984  163 False   Empty
> 4 0   26  113 339  38912  151 False   Empty
> 5 2   26  113 452  54528  212 False   Empty
> 6 4   26  113 565  16640  64  False   Empty
> 7 6   26  113 678  5376   20  False   Empty
> 8 8   26  113 791  48384  188 False   Empty
> 9 10  26  113 904  45824  178 False   Empty
> 10    12  26  113 1017 30464  118 False   Empty
> ```

The rows of the table represent each step a player takes in a game. This is not my game, I have reverse-engineered the mechanics of a popular console game (`Step` object generates the correct stats).

So, the table will represent the path taken by someone playing the game; as such they will need to add their input to the table. Adding input changes the subsequent values in the table. The table then acts as a record, or a route-planner, for what the user will do when playing the game on a console.

The below code is all from `Table` class:

```python
from row_maker_inlined import Step
from math import trunc

class Table(object):
    ''' A table of steps. '''

    def __init__(self, dist, start):
        ''' Accepts a dict of starting stats. '''
        self._dist = dist
        self.maker = Step(start)
        self._rows = [self.maker.step]
        self._input_history = {}
        self._position = None
        self._adj_dist = dist

    @property
    def rows(self):
        return self._rows

    @property
    def dist(self):
        return self._dist

    @property
    def adj_dist(self):
        return self._adj_dist

    @property
    def input_history(self):
        return self._input_history

    def makeNext(self):
        ''' Returns the next row. '''
        self.maker.next()
        return self.maker.step

    def setMaker(self, stats):
        ''' Sets the maker generator to position n. '''
        self.maker.step = stats

    def build(self):
        ''' Builds the entire table. '''
        while len(self._rows) < self._adj_dist:
            self._rows.append(self.makeNext())

    def show(self):
        ''' Displays the table. '''
        print 'Table:\n'
        for i in self._rows:
            print '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}'.format(
            i['n'],i['step'],i['o'],i['i'],i['dng'],i['lmt'],i['r'],i['enc'],i['inp'])
```

The Table accepts input. **Here are the methods that deal with input**. I keep wondering if a separate Editor or Input class would be better for handling this? And then the Table could have an Input object within it.

```python
    def input(self, input, pos):
        ''' Checks input is valid before adding. '''
        if input == 'G' and not self._rows[pos]['enc']:
            print '*** Cannot add', input, 'to this row:'
            print self._rows[pos]['n'], '\n'
        elif (input == 'Empty') and (self._rows[pos]['inp'] != 'Empty'):
            self._position = pos
            self.clearInput(input, pos)
            self.update()
        elif (input == 'W') and (not self._rows[pos]['enc']):
            self._position = pos
            self.addInput(input, pos)
            self.update()
        else:
            self._position = pos
            self.addInput(input, pos)
            self.update()

    def addInput(self, input, position):
        ''' Accepts an input and an index position. Sets the input at rows[position]. '''
        self._rows[position]['inp'] = input
        self.addToHistory(input, position)

    def clearInput(self, input, position):
        ''' Clears the input from table[position] to 'Empty'. '''
        modified = self._rows[position]
        if modified['inp'] != 'Empty':
            self._rows[position]['inp'] = 'Empty'
            self.removeFromHistory(modified['n'])
        else:
            print '*** Input is already empty:', modified['inp'], '\n'

    def addToHistory(self, input, position):
        ''' Adds the most recent input to the history. '''
        modified = self._rows[position]
        self._input_history[modified['n']] = input

    def removeFromHistory(self, row_key):
        ''' Removes input from input history. Row key is 'n' value . '''
        del self.input_history[row_key]

    def deleteOldInput(self):
        ''' Deletes input that has been removed due to table resize. '''
        last_row_num = self._rows[-1]['n']
#       Add old input to list.
        old_input = [i for i in self.input_history.iterkeys() if i > last_row_num]
#       Iterate through deletion list and delete from input_history.
        for num in old_input:
            self.removeFromHistory(num)
            print '*** Removed old input from input_history.'
```

This section deal with updating the Table. If, for example, I add input to row 1, this will have an affect on all of the rows below it. The following methods deal with updating or refreshing the table:

```python
    def calcWalks(self):
        ''' Returns the number of walks in the input table. '''
        walks = 0
        for key, val in self.input_history.iteritems():
            if val == 'W':
                walks += 1
        return walks

    def calcDist(self):
        ''' Returns the adjusted distance that includes walks. '''
#       TODO: Add stutter calculations for adding.
        return self._dist + trunc(self.calcWalks() * 0.25)
```

The Table grows or reduces depending on input too:

```python
    def checkTableLength(self, length):
        ''' Checks table size and adds/removes rows. '''
#       Table is too short:
        if length < self.adj_dist:
#       The new row is based on the last row in the table.
            self.setMaker(self._rows[-1])
            self.build()
            print '*** Table extended.'
#       Table is too long:
        elif length > self.adj_dist:
#           The amount of rows to remove.
            extra = length - self.adj_dist
            self._rows = self._rows[:-abs(extra)]
            print '*** Table reduced.'
#           Position should point to the last row, so others do not update.
            self._position = len(self._rows) - 1
#           Keep input history up-to-date by removing input that no longer exists.
            self.deleteOldInput()



    def update(self):
        ''' Updates all table data. '''
#       Update field distance based on the number of walks.
        self._adj_dist = self.calcDist()
        length = len(self._rows)
        if length != self.adj_dist:
            self.checkTableLength(length)
        self.updateRows()

    def updateRows(self):
        ''' Recalculates and updates, danger, enc, and input. '''
        self.setMaker(self._rows[self._position])
#       Update the rows that require updating; starting from the modified row.
        for row in self._rows[self._position:]:
            updated = self.maker.step
            row['dng'] = updated['dng']
            row['enc'] = updated['enc']
#           Remove redundant input:
            if row['inp'] == 'G' and not row['enc']:
                row['inp'] = 'Empty'
                self.removeFromHistory((row['n']))
#           Advance the row maker, in order to generate the next row.
            self.maker.next()

    def getEncs(self):
        ''' Returns a list of encounters. '''
        return [(i['n'] - 1, i['inp']) for i in self._rows if i['enc']]
```

[Full source for `Table`](http://pastebin.com/H5biR2Er)

**My main problem is with the concept of single responsibility**. The Table is responsible for almost everything; accepting input, validating input, resizing, editing row values, etc.

What should the Table be responsible for? How can I know? Because the Table is the center of the program, it seems it should be responsible for everything...

I need to get out of the mindset of creating one or two classes with tons of methods, but I don't know how.

It would be very helpful if someone could point out what could be made into new classes. And how those objects will be structured, eg. *A Table has an editor object that accepts and is responsible for input.*

I really want to learn good OOP design, however that is difficult; programming is a hobby for me, self-taught, no formal teaching.